# Insert a header of one file into the top of another

Tags: bash

I split a number of csv files into two halves each. But every of those files had a header, so now the second halves of the files are missing headers.

How do I insert the top line of file A into the top of file B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using command substitution to extract the first line of file1 and then using sed in place replacement for first line in file2.

```
 sed -i "1s/^/$(head -n1 file1)\n/" file2
```

Comment: Thx. Can you please what's happening inside " "?

Comment: `1s1 in the `sed` command means, search and replace only on first line. `^` means start of the  line. and `head -n1 file1` will get the first line of file1. So `/^/$(head -n1 file1)/` means replace first line of file2 with first line of file1.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite the second file. Assuming that you have the files `first.csv` and `second.csv` you can do it like that:

```
head -n1 first.csv > second-new.csv
cat second.csv >> second-new.csv
```

You can now inspect `second-new.csv` to see if everything is ok and then replace the old version with:

```
mv -i second-new.csv second.csv
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in one step?

Comment: It is not possible to insert data at the beginning of a file.